# Floating div overlap msie

Tags: html, css

Ive been banging my head with why MSIE8 doesnt overlap the floating div just as webkit a mozilla both do. I hope you guys can help me out with this one.

I have the following code:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
<html>
  <head>
    <title></title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <link rel="style" href="style.css" type="text/css" />
  </head>
  <body style="margin: 0px; background: #3b0404;">
      <div align="center">
          <div id="top" style="height: 100px; background: yellow; width: 100%;max-height: 100px; ">
              <div style="overflow: visible; width: 800px; height: 100px; max-height: 100px; background: aquamarine;">
                <div id="logo" style="float: left; margin-left: -3px; width: 203px; height: 201px; background: pink; overflow: visible;"></div>
                <div id="menu" style="float: right; width: 595px; height: 100px; background: blue;"></div>
              </div>
          </div>
          <div id="content" style="width: 800px; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;">
              <div style="background: purple; height: 215px;"></div>
              <div style="background: green; height: 350px;"></div>
          </div>
          <div id="bottom"></div>
      </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

I need the pink div to overlap the purple one while maintaining dimensions, however MSIE8 keeps expanding the containing divs so it pushes everything down instead of the desired behaviour.

I hope my question is clear, I dont know if Im doing something wrong and should take a different approach.

Thanks for your help!!

Comment: by the way, I dont have a place to post this example.. is there a sandbox html site I should know of??

Comment: Looks OK to me in IE8 on @Michael's link.  I did notice that the pink div ends up behind the purple one in IE7 compatibility mode, but otherwise it seemed to work.

Comment: @derekerdmann i may be asking a stupid question but whats compatibility mode? Also, i really need the pink div over the purple one =/ and ive ran out of ideas.

Comment: @dabito - Compatibility mode is where IE8 renders the page with the IE7 engine, so that websites that haven't been made to work in the newer rendering engine can still be viewed.  You can trigger it manually by clicking the little torn-page icon near the refresh button.

Answer (score 0):

It was the transitional DOCTYPE .. it looked fine on JSFiddle cause it added the strict dtd.

Thanks to everyone for your time.